# How can I select the genres of a movie from a many-to-many genre2movie table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables `movie`, `genre`, `movie2genre`

`genre` has `genreid` and `name`

`movie2genre` has `movieid` and `genreid`

I want to write a query where I pass movieid and I get rows of the genres that movie has. How can I do this?

Comment: I still remember the days when we were allowed to write: what have you tried?

Comment: Those were the days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM movie2genre 
JOIN Genre on Genre.GenreId = movie2genre.GenreId 
JOIN Movie on Movie.MovieId = movie2genre.MovieId 
WHERE Movie.MovieId = [MovieId passed in]
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM genre WHERE genreid IN(SELECT genreid FROM movie2genre WHERE movieid=[ID])
```

Answer (score -2):

First, if you want to pass on something, you are looking at stored procedure.

Second, [image: joins]you need to join everything on ID's; You can refer to the image and later show us something what you tried.